# What does the error "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state." mean?

Tags: javascript, iframe, service-worker, chromium

I'm trying to register a service worker from an iframe that is created dynamically like this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = '
<head><script src="/script.js"></script></head>
<body>Iframe</body>
';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

`script.js` contains the code that registers a service worker (texbook example from google's documentation).

This throws an error saying `"Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state."`

I tried having the service worker registration code in the 'load' event handler of the iframe and adding a timeout to account for the service worker registration code potentially being called at a bad time without any success.

In the source code of Chromium I found the following code which is where I think the error is coming from:

```
if (!m_provider) {
        resolver->reject(DOMException::create(InvalidStateError, "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state."));
        return promise;
    }
```

What does "The document is in an invalid state" mean in this context?
What is `m_provider` and why is it that it's not available?

Comment: Were you using HTTPS or localhost?

Comment: I'm using localhost over http

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67698176/11107541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be caused by a bug in Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1102209

Ideally, the dynamically-created frame would inherit the services workers registered on the parent, eliminating the need to write in the iframe's contentWindow at all.